# What is the difference between current_user and @current_user (I am using devise) ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know @current_user is instance variable but I am still unclear about the difference between current_user and @current_user ? when should i use current_user and when @current_user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience with devise I never use @current_user, current_user always suffices wherever and whenever I want.

The official documentation only mentions current_user too.
[Devise Controllers filters and helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is the helper method provided by devise to access the current user. There is nothing like `@current_user` from devise unless you have set it in your code.

Comment: The devise code performs @current_user ||= warden.authenticate(...). This means devise is setting the instance variable. current_user is the right thing to use.